# How to find nonhomogeneous solutions of the following PDE: $b^2d_{,xx}+d-1=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have a question about the solutions for the following PDE.
$$
b^2d_{,xx}+d-1=0, \text{where}\quad x,b\in \mathbb{R} \quad\text{and} \quad b>0
$$

It is easy to verify that $d=1$ is a homogeneous solution and $d(x)=1-\sin \left(\frac{|x|}{b}\right)$ is also a solution which is nonhomogeneous. The problem is when I use COMSOL Multiphysics to solve this equation, I can only get the homogeneous solution and by no means the nonhomogeneous one. I can see that the nonhomogeneous solution is not continuous which may be the reason why I can't get it. Is there any way to get this solution through a numerical way? Thanks!

Comment: In what sense is this a PDE? Your only derivatives seem to be with respect to $x$.

Comment: Is b a constant ?

Comment: The original equation contains $\Delta d$ and this is a 1-D version of the original equation. b is a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$b^2d_{,xx}+d-1=0$$
Rewrite it as:
$$b^2(d-1)_{,xx}+(d-1)=0$$
$$b^2w_{,xx}+w=0$$
Where $w=d-1$. Then the DE is homogeneous.

The characteristic polynomial is $(b \ne 0)$:
$$b^2r^2+1=0 \implies (br-i)(br+i)=0$$
$$\implies r=\pm \dfrac i b$$
The solution is :
$$w(x)=c_1 \cos (x/b)+c_2 \sin(x/b)$$
And
$$d(x)=1+w(x)$$
$$d(x)=1+c_1 \cos (x/b)+c_2 \sin(x/b)$$

Comment: Thanks! I think you solved my problem.

Comment: You're very welcome John @JohnLionel